# Simulate a Delete with Firebase

Tags: firebase

In the "Simulator" built into the Firebase site is it possible to simulate deleting a node?

I tried entering the path to a node in the **URL field** (e.g. `/my/path/-JCNAUFZJFJMGX1RYWJL`) and I entered `{}` into the **data field** but I think this just simulates adding nothing as apposed to deleting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firebase, writing a `null` value is equivalent to removing the data at a given reference (i.e. `ref.set(null)` is effectively the same as `ref.remove()`), and thus using a `null` value is an effective way to test removing data in the simulator.

Comment: I think I even tried that but must have forgotten to click authenticate or something because I wasn't getting the expected results. Working now though. Thanks!

Comment: Firebase Simulator doesn't allow me to pass nothing to the data field. It says 'Invalid JSON'. When I input 'null', it says '
Keys cannot contain $ # [ ] / or .'

Comment: @DavidVávra Perhaps post a screenshot here, or reach out to Firebase support? In a quick test, I was able to both write `null` and `{}` via the simulator to test data removal.

Comment: @RobDiMarco I managed it at the end, `null` does write that error message, but it simulates the delete anyways.